# MVC 5 - Partial view not showing data

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, partial-views

I have a company model as seen below.

The company model has an `IQueryable` of EmailHistory (this is another model).

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string CompanyName { get; set; }
public IQueryable<IEmailHistory> EmailHistory { get; set; }
```

In my company controller i get my company details and get all my email history records, so this is my controller.

```
//Go to the repository and the company record
var companyRecord = TheRepository.GetCompany(transaction.CompanyId, User.Identity.GetUserId());

//Get the emails for this company
companyRecord.EmailHistory = TheRepository.GetEmailHistoryByCompany(User.Identity.GetUserId(),
            Id);
```

If i expand the results at this point in the controller i can see emails for the company.... so far everything is ok.

My company page has a partial view for the email history.

```
@ Html.Partial("~/Views/EmailHistory/_EmailHistories.cshtml", Model.EmailHistory);
```

The partial looks like this:

```
@model List<AutoSend.Model.IEmailHistory>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:100px" class="text-left">To</th>
            <th style="width:60px" class="text-left">Sent Date</th>
            <th style="width:60px" class="text-left">OutCome</th>
            <th style="width:60px" class="text-left">Delivered Date</th>
            <th style="width:60px" class="text-left">Opened Date</th>       
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var emailHistory in Model)
        {
            <tr>
            <td class="text-left">@Html.Display(emailHistory.EmailAddress)</td>
            <td class="text-left">@Html.Display(emailHistory.SentDate.ToShortDateString())</td>
            <td class="text-left">@Html.Display(emailHistory.OutCome)</td>
            <td class="text-left">@Html.Display(emailHistory.EmailDeliveredDate.ToShortDateString())</td>
            <td class="text-left">@Html.Display(emailHistory.EmailOpened.ToShortDateString())            </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If i step through this i can see that we loop through the email history (and can see the values) fine but..... The page never actually renders out the data (although the associated td's are rendered)

I can see the table headers and rows but no records are being shown!?

Comment: in the loop are you seeing the associated values also?

Comment: can you provide content of css class 'text-left'?

Comment: If it's looping then you'd still see empty td's in the DOM.  If you don't see those then it's not looping

Comment: Ok, silly point here, but could it all be because of the space here: `@ Html.Partial` ??

Comment: I can see the empty td's so i dont think its the looping

Comment: what if you change the Html.Display to Html.Label or something of that nature?

Comment: Try removing the `@Html.Display` and just reference the individual field names, like `@emailHistory.EmailAddress`.

Answer (score 1):

How about rendering data in the tds without the helper method..... like  @emailhistory.[yourprop]....

Comment: When rendering out the raw data without the helper method the data does show!?